# A store that sells one type of item

Tags: java

Okay, I don't know If I wrote a code correctly please check. So I created software for a store that sells one type of item. And each instance of my class should be an item of merchandise my store sells.

For example if my store sells neckties, I would design a necktie class:

**class Necktie { …**

My class must have five instance variables, including at least one of type integer, at least one of type String and one called price which must be double. Also it should have a toString method that accepts no parameters and returns a description of the item. It should have a constructor. The constructor can take however many parameters you choose, but it must set all instance variables.

•   It should contain an accessor method for each instance variable.

•   It should contain no unnecessary instance variables. Any information that does not need to be stored in an instance of your class should be stored as local variables.

Here is the code below. (incomplete, because I am kinda stuck..Please check if I did it correctly. If not, then please correct me.)

```
public class Pets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.print (Pets.toString()); //toString
    }

    String color, pattern;
    int age, size;
    double price;

    Pets (String color, String pattern, int age, int size, double price){
        this.color = color;
        this.pattern = pattern;
        age = age;
        size = size;
        price = price;
    }
    public String toString(){     //I don't get this part..
        String description;
        description = "red";
        return description;
    }
    public String getColor(){
        return color;           
    }

    public String getPattern(){
        return pattern;
    }

    public int age(){
        return age;
    }

    public int size(){
        return size;
    }

    public double price(){
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to know if I did it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Does it compile? Does it run? Does it do what you expect? if yes to all these you did it correctly. If not, look at the error messages or trace the code to find out what you did wrong.

Comment: System.out.print (Pets.toString()); Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method toString() from the type Object and I don't know if I follow the instruction correctly.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759973/how-to-run-instance-methods-from-main

Answer (score 0):

Your main method tries to call a static method toString(), but your toString() method is not static (as it shouldn't be).

For testing purposes, your main method should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pets pet = new Pets("red", "plain", 1, 2, 10.25);
    System.out.println(pet.toString());
}
```

In your constructor:

```
Pets (String color, String pattern, int age, int size, double price){
    this.color = color;
    this.pattern = pattern;
    this.age = age;
    this.size = size;
    this.price = price;
}
```

Your `toString()` method has a typo in the name. It should probably return a description of the attributes of the instance (not an actual description field). For example:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder description = new StringBuilder("Color: ")
            .append(color)
            .append(", Pattern: ")
            .append(pattern)
            .append(", Age: ")
            .append(age)
            .append(", Size: ")
            .append(size)
            .append(", Price: ")
            .append(price);
    return description.toString();
}
```

Your getters should start with get:

```
public int getAge(){
    return age;
}

public int getSize(){
    return size;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
```

**Edit**

At the OPs request:

An alternative toString() method which uses String concatenation (bad) and no special formatting:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Color: " + color + ", Pattern: " + pattern + ", Age: " + age + ", Size: " + size + ", Price: " + price;
}
```

Comment: is there any easy way? instead of using .append

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: My output is really weird. It's Pets@32c5f9fe

Comment: That's because you haven't got the signature of your toString() method right. Check that it is: `public String toString() {...}`. The default `Object.toString()` prints the name of the class and reference (which is what you are seeing).

Comment: Edited to include test version of `main()` method

Answer (score 0):

Where you've written

```
    age = age;
    size = size;
    price = price;
```

This is actually not setting the instance variable. You should carry on writing

```
   this.age = age
   // etc...
```

When you write `this` it tells Java that you're referring to the instance variable, not the local variable

Answer (score 0):

When the `main` method is called, Java doesn't create an instance of `Pets` for you.  But the rest of your code works on a `Pets` object, so you'll need to create one somewhere in your `main`.  Thus, instead of:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print (Pets.toString()); //toString
}
```

it will be something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pets pet = new Pets(........);      // creates an instance; you'll need to supply
                                        // the arguments
    System.out.print (pet.toString());  // calls toString on this instance
}
```

That will get past the "cannot make a static reference" error, but there are other problems as described in other answers.